# Is there a way to have a list of unity events?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I am trying to do is that I have made an RecipeManager, which I have a list of the Recipe custom class inside which allows me to select and create recipes that are per scene, and that is also where I am going to keep the events that I create. Think of the events as steps in a recipe.
The idea I have had to make a recipe system is that there will be an array of events (steps) and when a step is completed it returns a bool, upon that bool being returned it will move onto the next step. I have it all imagined but I do not know where to start with it. Perhaps something along the lines of:

```
public List<Events> steps = new List<Events>();

public void IterateThroughSteps()
{
    foreach(var step in steps)
    {
       if(step.isCompleted) // isCompleted is a bool which is true upon the event being triggered
       {
           // Remove step from list
       }
    }
}
```

Summary: How do I make a list / array of unity events which can be modular per recipe?

Hopefully this question is up to standards, thanks for your time.

Comment: Then why you want to have a list of events ? You can just create all different events/functions/methods and at step one just call first function then if the result of this is true you call another function and so on ...

Comment: @RaoHammas that sounds about right... But if I have a list of events / functions then I can make it as long or as short as the recipe is. This way it is fully modular and I don't have to create a script for every recipe.

Answer (score 1):

Just having list of events won't do much in your case.

Your recipe could be container for steps.

```
public class Recipe : MonoBehaviour
{
    private readonly List<RecipeStep> steps = new List<RecipeStep>(0);
}
```

Now, your steps could be simple components with index numbers (or other technique for setting the order index). If you go with component approach, consider this:

Create custom unity event to support step completion:

```
[System.Serializable]
public sealed class RecipeStepCompletedEvent : UnityEvent<RecipeStep>
{ }
```

Now, create base class for all your possible steps:

```
public abstract class RecipeStep : MonoBehaviour
{
    public RecipeStepCompletedEvent StepCompleted;

    public int orderIndex;
}
```

Now, to collect all steps for recipe, just add to `Recipe.cs`

```
...
private void Awake()
{
    var recipeSteps = GetComponents<RecipeStep>();

    steps.Clear();
    steps.Addrange(recipeSteps);

    // 1. Do sorting by order index or however you like
    // 2. Disable all steps (leave only first step enabled) (steps[X].enabled = false;)
    // 3. Listen to each steps StepCompleted event to be able to progress as step is finished
}
```

Now let's create step, that waits for user pressing spacebar

```
public sealed class KeyPressRecipeStep : RecipeStep
{
    public KeyCode desiredKey;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(desiredKey))
        {
            StepCompleted.Invoke(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this approach allows you to easily extend recipes and steps depending on your needs. And `Update()` method is not run on components that are disabled, thus saving some precious CPU cycles.

Comment: Wow, this seems awesome. But I don't know if I am on board with the idea of creating a new class for each event. In addition to that, there will be many recipes so having all of those components will be high maintenance

Comment: It really depends on your use case. There probably are alternatives but then we should know more about what type of actions can be for a recipe step, how much it can vary, etc.

Comment: Ah okay well for what it's worth the recipes are randomly picked, and they are set per scene. So I can have different recipes for different game settings i.e spaceship or busy city. Ideally I can use events and select which events are needed for which step but I have no idea how to approach it whilst keeping it easy and modular. I was worried that if I just mix and match steps there might be infinite errors.

Comment: Have you looked at prefabs? You could create each recipe (with all steps) as prefab and then instantiate that prefab. You could have your scenarios done that way. Or, you can randomly generate `RecipeStep` on GameObject using `AddComponent`, and then add `Recipe` component after all steps are added.

Comment: That could be interesting. Like I would have a script with all events and then I just select which ones I want, but I think I would still run into the problem of the steps not working when mashed together.

Comment: You will never know until you try. There might be many side effects or it might work like a charm - it all depends on how you link everything up.

Comment: Yep, I will let you know. Thanks for your help